# Convert JSON to XML with attributes

Tags: java, json, xml, xstream

I am using XStream to de/serialize objects to JSON.

I need to convert the JSON to XML attributes.

For example:

**JSON**

```
{
      "Student":{
           "@Studentname":"Ravi",
           "@age":21,
           "college":"Anna University"
       }
}
```

**Output XML**

```
<Student name="Ravi" age=21>
  <college>Anna University</college>
</Student>
```

**code**

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.registerConverter(new MapEntryConverter());
xstream.alias("Student", Map.class);
xml = xstream.toXML(json.map()); //json stores the value
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try ?? Any code.

Comment: have you tried org,json

Comment: [This](http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html) would help.