# Convert JSON to XML with attributes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I need to convert the JSON to XML with some properties as attributes.

For example:

**JSON**

```
{
      "Student":{
           "@Studentname":"Ravi",
           "@age":21,
           "college":"Anna University"
       }
}
```

**Desired Output XML**

```
<Student name="Ravi" age=21>
  <college>Anna University</college>
</Student>
```

Comment: Posting this as a new question targeted to JavaScript but itis essentially a duplicate of a Java based question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137318/convert-json-to-xml-with-attributes/71846457#71846457

Comment: If none of the standard conversion libraries do exactly what you want, you could consider doing a custom conversion using XSLT 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [x2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x2js) library.

The default attribute prefix is "_"  but can be overridden by using the `attributePrefix` config setting.

```js
const X2JS = window.X2JS;  // node: require('x2js')


const x2js = new X2JS({ attributePrefix:"@" })

const jsonObj = {"Student":{"@Studentname":"Ravi","@age":21,"college":"Anna University"}}

const xmlString = x2js.js2xml(jsonObj)

console.log(xmlString)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/x2js@3.2.3/x2js.js"></script>
```